# Transforming stacked records into a columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', index_col=None)

print(df)
>>>>

   report   action    label
0       1  disable  label_a
1       1  disable  label_b
2       1  disable  label_c
3       2    alert  label_b
4       2    alert  label_c
5       3   ignore  label_a
6       3   ignore  label_c
```

What I would like to do is transform it into:

```
   report   action  label_a  label_b  label_c
0       1  disable        1        1        1
1       2    alert        0        1        1
2       3   ignore        1        0        1
```

Basically grouping the rows together by `report` (and `action`, but `action` is always the same for every `report` row), and then blow out the labels into their own columns with ones or zeros indicating whether or not they were present as a row in the original data.

[This SO question gets me pretty close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545613/python-pandas-transforming-dataframe), but I can't figure out how to group by `report` without losing label data from the grouped rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `pivot_table()`:

```
df.pivot_table(rows=("report", "action"), 
               cols="label", 
               values="label", 
               aggfunc="count").fillna(0)
```

The output:

```
label           label_a  label_b  label_c
report action                            
1      disable        1        1        1
2      alert          0        1        1
3      ignore         1        0        1
```